# Unix - delete files and folders excluding PATTERN

Tags: command-line, unix

Recently I was faced with the task of deleting all the files/folders in a directory excluding those matching a specific pattern.  So I cooked up a single-line unix command to do the work.  Must it be only one line?  I suppose not, but it's definitely cooler that way!

While the problem is pretty simple, I was a little surprised at how complex my solution ended up being.  Here's the command I used; NOTE: this is a poor solution because it doesn't handle filenames containing line-feed characters (which didn't matter in my situation).

```
ls | grep -v PATTERN | xargs -n1 -IREPLACE rm -rf REPLACE
```

I did not use the "find" command because I do not want to recurse into folders matching PATTERN.  For example, consider the following file structure:

```
file_foo.txt
first_dir
  |
  +--> contents
  +--> ...
foo_dir
  |
  +--> anotherfile.txt
  +--> morefiles.log
foo_file.txt
somefile.txt
```

Using pattern "foo" must only remove "first_dir" (and it's contents of course) and "somefile.txt" (**not** "anotherfile.txt" or "morefiles.log").

Question, are there better (more elegant and correct) ways to accomplish this?

EDIT:
It was recently brought to my attention that "find" may be a *better* option:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 ! -name PATTERN -print0 | xargs -0n1 rm -rf
```

This solution does correctly handle paths containing line-feed characters.

Comment: EDIT: changed erroneous "the_dir" to correct "first_dir".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following examples have `echo` prefixed so that you can test the patterns before actually using them. Remove the `echo` to activate the `rm -rf`. Substitute `rm -ri` to prompt for confirmation.

*ksh* has a negative match extension to its globbing:

```
# ksh
echo rm -rf !(*foo*)
```

The same syntax is available in *bash* if you set the `extglob` option:

```
# bash
shopt -s extglob
echo rm -rf !(*foo*)
```

*zsh* has its own syntax for this:

```
# zsh
setopt extended_glob
echo rm -rf ^*foo*
```

It can also use the *ksh*-style syntax:

```
# zsh: ksh-style glob syntax
setopt ksh_glob no_bare_glob_qual
echo rm -rf !(*foo*)

# zsh: ksh-style glob syntax, adapted for the default bare_glob_qual option
setopt ksh_glob bare_glob_qual
echo rm -rf (!(*foo*))
```

Comment: Simple, elegant, handles linefeed characters, (almost) one line (I've added `shopt -s extglob` to my .bashrc file, so it now **is** a one-liner).  Perfect!  I promise an upvote as soon as my reputation allows it.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another `find` solution.  I'm not sure this has any real advantage over yours, but it doesn't need `xargs` and allows for the rare possibility that * expands to too many names.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name PATTERN -type f -delete
```

I also added `-type f` so that it would not attempt to delete directories.

Warning: `-delete` is powerful. I gave one of my test files 0 permissions and the command above deleted it without hesitation.

Comment: Test first. Replace `-delete` with `-print` to see if it's finding the files you wanted. If all is good, use the command history (e.g. press the up button) to get back to the previous command to ensure that you're working with the same find filters.

Comment: Read carefully, note that I *do* wish to remove directories.  And `find -delete` will not remove non-empty directories.  Also notice that `find -maxdepth 1` matches "." (current directory) which is really bad. Although I do like your idea of eliminating `xargs`, one might use `find -exec` alternatively.  `find * -maxdepth 0 ! -name PATTERN -exec rm -rf '{}' \;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use this rebol script example http://askcodegeneration.com/keep-subversion/  instead which is much more understandable and which can manage user interaction like folder selection and confirmation:

```
delete-file: func[file][
    if/else none? find file "/.svn/" [
        delete file
    ][
        print ["keeping" file]
    ]
]
dir: request-dir
ans: ask rejoin ["Do you confirm " dir "? (Yes): "]
if (ans = "Yes") [
    foreach-file dir :delete-file
]
```